Substring matching with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
I'm trying to find a match of substring with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.
For example, looking for "abc" in "123AbC123" should return "AbC".
To do so, I tried to use Regex:
static string IgnoreCaseMatch(string substring, string str)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(str, Regex.Escape(substring), RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (match.Success)
    { 
        return match.Groups[0].Value;
    }

    return null;
}

But when I try some complex examples, such as IgnoreCaseMatch("ﬀ", "FF") I get null instead of FF, while string.Equals("ﬀ", "FF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) returns true.
Which means that string comparison with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase knows that ﬀ is actually FF in different case, but RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase doesn't make the match.
So, how can I implement substring matching mechanism with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase?
Based on the comments I get, please note that ﬀ and FF are special casing according to the official Unicode specs

It is just that RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase is not equal to StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase. Normalize the input if you need to get the expected output.

@WiktorStribiżew can you please elaborate? How can I normalize it?

String.Normalize Method

More specifically, you probably want str.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC)

But then I will match different substring. For example, looking for "FF" in "Eﬀort" I will get "ff" (two normal "f"s) instead of "ﬀ" (the special character as appeared in the original string)

Here is an example. Then what is the problem? It seems you just want to find in all similarly looking texts.

@WiktorStribiżew I need the substring of str that is match to the searched string substring, when I do IgnoreCaseMatch("FF", "Eﬀort"), I will get "ff" (two normal "f"s) instead of "ﬀ" (the special character as appeared in the original string) which is a new string that is not a substring of the original string I used

I believe it is a similar case to Polish ł normalization: it is just considered a separate letter, and is not thus part of any decomposition scheme. All you can do to match it is creating a separate character class. So, in your case, there is no other way other than using FF|ﬀ and then return match.Value.Replace("ﬀ", "ff"). At any rate, ﬀ is always used in the lowercase context.

@nrofis: you seem to have enough reputation to be able to write some unit tests so that people can read your question and get the details of what you want. The "AbC" example is only tangentially related to the problem.

Do you actually want to use OrdinalIgnoreCase? InvariantCultureIgnoreCase and OrdinalIgnoreCase are not the same. Ordinal compares Unicode code point values, while InvariantCulture performs a culture-sensitive comparison in some "standard culture" (en-us I believe but I could be wrong). See e.g. Difference between InvariantCulture and Ordinal string comparison and String comparisons that use the current culture.

Possibly relevant: this answer by Evgeniy Berezovsky to Why is regex.IsMatch(str) faster than str.EndsWith (invariant culture)? ) claims that RegexOptions.CultureInvariant does not imply things implied by StringComparison.InvariantCulture. Is RegexOptions.CultureInvariant perhaps more like StringComparison.Ordinal?  If that is correct it would explain what you are seeing.

@dbc OP hasn't brought up OrdinalIgnoreCase, not sure why you did. Especially since it clearly is not what OP wants here - OP has unambiguously explained they expect "ﬀ" and "FF" to match each other.

I came up with the following:

get the index of the match
determine the longest possible substring length considering ligatures expanded (normalized)
determine the shortest possible substring length considering ligatures condensed
brute force the way down (not very smart)

You could probably optimize this using a divide and conquer algorithm (like binary search) for the substring length. And you probably should, if your substrings are longer than a few characters.
static string IgnoreCaseMatch(string substring, string str)
{
    int index = str.IndexOf(substring, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    if (index == -1) return null;

    var needle_normalized = substring.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC);  
    var length = needle_normalized.Length;
    if (length == 0) return string.Empty;

    var minlength = needle_normalized.Length/"ffl".Length; // Assume that ffl is the longest ligature   
    str = str.Substring(index, length); // A minor optimization for the following .Substring() calls
    while(length > minlength) 
    {
        var part = str.Substring(0, length);        
        bool isEqual = string.Equals(part, substring, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (isEqual) return part;
        length--;
    }
    
    
    throw new Exception("Unexpected. The developer of this method put a lot of thought into this, but must have missed something. Please report the test case '" + substring + "'/'" + str + "' and blame StackOverflow for bad implementations."); 
}

Test cases:
Console.WriteLine(IgnoreCaseMatch("eff", "My ﬀ***ing eﬀort") == "eﬀ");
Console.WriteLine(IgnoreCaseMatch("eFF", "My ﬀ***ing eﬀort") == "eﬀ");
Console.WriteLine(IgnoreCaseMatch("eﬀ", "My ﬀ***ing eﬀort") == "eﬀ");
Console.WriteLine(IgnoreCaseMatch("eﬀ", "My ﬀ***ing effort") == "eff");
Console.WriteLine(IgnoreCaseMatch("eﬀ", "My ﬀ***ing eFFort") == "eFF");


And don't ask ChatGPT to implement such a binary search unless you can check the correctness with Unit Tests. It got it wrong in 2/2 attempts, LOL
